# Getting Issues implementing redis pub/sub with websockets using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, redis, node-redis

I tried to implement pub/sub with redis using websockets in Nodejs. My task is to implement selective message delivery based on subscriber interests. For example, suppose there are 03 subscribers and two of them subscribed to "BOARD-A" and third one subscribed to channel "BOARD-B". If publisher publish messages on channel "BOARD-A" then only "BOARD-A" subscriber should receive messages.
Currently what's happened that all active subscribers receive message including third subscriber.

It would be great if someone should suggest what needs to improve or what mistakes I have done so far or I haven't handled the business logic.

I've attached the code and relevant screenshots:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const Redis = require('ioredis');

// Create a WebSocket server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

// Create a Redis client for subscribing to channels
const redisSubscriber = new Redis();

// Create a Redis client for publishing messages
const redisPublisher = new Redis();

// WebSocket server event: connection established
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  // WebSocket event: message received from client
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message);

    if (data.event === 'subscribe') {
      // Subscribe to a Redis channel
      redisSubscriber.subscribe(data.channel);
      redisSubscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => {
        // Send Redis messages to the client
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ channel, message }));
      });
    } else if (data.event === 'publish') {
      // Publish a message to a Redis channel
      redisPublisher.publish(data.channel, data.message);
    }
  });

  // WebSocket event: connection closed
  ws.on('close', () => {
    // Unsubscribe from all Redis channels
    redisSubscriber.unsubscribe();
  });
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]